# Are the canisters for isoButane (empty weight) heavier than other Butane mixes?

Tags: canister-stoves

I'm planning to use a butane "canister stove". The only canisters I can find locally are Butane/**Propane** mixes.

My understanding is that Propane canisters are extra heavy b/c Propane is under higher pressure.

Are Butane /Propane canisters heavier then other Butane mixes?

Comment: Side note: Butane boils at -1C, normally propane is preferred for cold climates, although cookers designed for with liquid feed are availble if going into sub freezing temperatures.

Comment: Does my answer answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

[The vapor pressure will increase significantly the more propane is in the mix.](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/propane-butane-mix-d_1043.html) More pressure means that a thicker/more resillient canister is needed to withstand it.

As you can see even with the most common 30/70 mix, the pressure is doubled or trippled depending on temperature.

[IsoButane has a greater vapor pressure than butane](http://www.cascadedesigns.com/msr/blog/ins-outs-canister-fuels/) (Although only slightly) - which will also translate to a slightly heavier canister.

Comment: This assumes that the canister is made stronger, as opposed to using the same canisters for both butane and butane/propane mixes.  (Similar to the reasoning behind "why do drive through ATM buttons have braille on them".)  Unfortunately I haven't seen pure butane canisters recently, only the mixes.

Comment: That might be true for some manufacturers. I do not have any data but I do think it is far more likely that a mass producer of butane would want to use dedicated butane canisters because the material costs would be significantly lower when scaled to the thousands/millions. From my personal experience, a butane canisters appears to be lighter. I do not have an empty mixed canister on hand to measure their weight however.